# Difference between using rownum before group by and after group by

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, rownum

I want to know the difference between following two queries

```
  SELECT INVN46, MTER46,CHRE46,CTSQ46, INFR46, INTO46
  FROM AULFXAF2.SSP46L01@FXA400HA10G 
  inner join Invoice_line_in line on line.invoice_line_id = trim(RECT46)|| '+'  || trim(INVN46) || '+' || trim(INVL46)
  where line.invoice_line_id like 'IN+Q%'
  and rownum <=1000
  group by INVN46, MTER46,CHRE46,CTSQ46, INFR46, INTO46;
```

and

```
  select * from 
  (SELECT INVN46, MTER46,CHRE46,CTSQ46, INFR46, INTO46
  FROM AULFXAF2.SSP46L01@FXA400HA10G 
  inner join Invoice_line_in line on line.invoice_line_id = trim(RECT46)|| '+'  || trim(INVN46) || '+' || trim(INVL46)
  where line.invoice_line_id like 'IN+Q%'
  group by INVN46, MTER46,CHRE46,CTSQ46, INFR46, INTO46)
  where rownum <=1000
```

Which one is accurate and fast ? According to my understanding first one gets the 1000 records and then group them together. I am not sure about the second one though.

Answer (score 1):

The first chooses 1000 records and then aggregates.

The second aggregates all the data and then chooses 1000 records from the result set.

Which is accurate?  That depends on what you want to do.  Which is faster?  Probably the first because it is filtering the data before aggregating it.

Comment: Thanks. makes sense now :)

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have a database with residents of a country, with their town and annual salary. You group by town and you add salaries together.

The first query selects 1000 random residents - they may all live in one town, or they may be from five or ten or thirty towns. Then you group by town and sum their salaries. Some towns will not be included in the result set; and for the towns that are, you get the sum of salaries of "some" (random) residents of that town. In most cases, this kind of query is useless.

The second query groups the residents by town and computes the total of salaries for each town. Then the outer query selects 1000 **random** towns from the country. (OK, it is a very large country, with over 1000 towns.) This query is a bit more helpful - although the fact that you select 1000 **random** towns makes it somewhat useless still.

Obviously the first query should be much faster, since it only looks at 1000 residents instead of, perhaps, 120 million residents. But this comparison is completely irrelevant, since the two queries do **very** different things.